# How to distinguish every other column from each other in a geom_bar() (ggplot), using fill patterns or a line around the columns?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have a bar plot showing 6 different treatments

[image: 6 Treatments plot]

Every other treatment is similar to the previous one except it contains oil. Therefore I want to keep the columns the same color two and two together, but I still want something to distinguish the ones with oil from the ones without oil. Therefore I wanted to add a pattern inside the ones with oil, but it seems like you need the `ggpattern` package which I have not been able to load since I'm using R version 4.0.2. Therefore, I was thinking a solution might be to insert a red "frame" or line around the oil columns, but I have not been able to find a code for that.

Hope someone can help me!

I have the following code:

```
# reproducible data
library(tidyverse)

mean_data <- tibble(
  Treatment = c("Control", "Scenario 1", "Scenario 2", "Control", "Ambient + oil", "Scenario 1", "Scenario 1 + oil", "Scenario 2", "Scenario 2 + oil", "Control", "Scenario 1", "Scenario 2", "Control", "Ambient + oil", "Scenario 1", "Scenario 1 + oil", "Scenario 2", "Scenario 2 + oil"),
  Species = rep(c("C.finmarchius", "C.glacialis"), each = 9),
  Day = rep(c(rep(1, 3), rep(6, 6)), 2),
  mean_area = runif(18, 0.1, 0.5),
  sd_area = runif(18, 0.01, 0.1),
  LSA = runif(18, 0.1, 0.5)
)


# Create a named vector of the Treatment labels
treatment_labels <- c("Control", "Ambient + oil", "Scenario 1", "Scenario 1 + oil", "Scenario 2", "Scenario 2 + oil")

# Create histograms with mean lipid sac area and standard deviation
histogram2 <- ggplot(mean_data, aes(x = Treatment, y = mean_area, fill = Treatment)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", alpha = 0.8) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean_area - sd_area, ymax = mean_area + sd_area), width = 0.1, position = "dodge", size = 0.3) +
  facet_grid(Species ~ paste0("Day ", Day), scales = "free_x") +
  labs(x = "", y = expression(LSA~"(mm"^2~")"), fill = "") +
  theme(strip.text.y = element_text(face = "italic")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#004C7E", "#004C7E", "#00BAC4", "#00BAC4", "#FFAA27", "#FFAA27"),
                    labels = treatment_labels) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Treatment")) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = NULL)


# Display the plot
print(histogram2)
```

Comment: You can use outline with aes `color` or `colour` something like `color = oil_segment` and then assign the `scale_color_manual` and using the color scale you prefer.

Comment: Hi Sofie! Welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: I added some data to your model, so it is reproducible by others. If you want, you could add the actual data (use `dput(mean_data)` and paste the results into your question)

Answer (score 1):

Adding code to illustrate [Sinh Nguyen's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76691444/how-to-distinguish-every-other-column-from-each-other-in-a-geom-bar-ggplot/76691688#comment135209904_76691444):

```
mean_data %>%
  mutate(oil_treatment = str_detect(Treatment, "oil")) %>% # adding a oil treatment column
  ggplot(aes(x = Treatment, y = mean_area, fill = Treatment, color = oil_treatment)) + # adding that as the colour argument
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", alpha = 0.8, size = 2) + # change the width with the size argument
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean_area - sd_area, ymax = mean_area + sd_area), width = 0.1, position = "dodge", size = 0.3) +
    facet_grid(Species ~ paste0("Day ", Day), scales = "free_x") +
    labs(x = "", y = expression(LSA~"(mm"^2~")"), fill = "") +
    theme(strip.text.y = element_text(face = "italic")) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#004C7E", "#004C7E", "#00BAC4", "#00BAC4", "#FFAA27", "#FFAA27"),
                      labels = treatment_labels) +
    guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Treatment")) +
    scale_x_discrete(breaks = NULL) + 
    scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "red")) # change the colour of the outlines of the bars
```

[image: plot]